# What are the improvised scenes from the Lord of the Rings trilogy?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, movie

I think one of the iconic improvised scenes was when Aragorn gave an energetic scream after kicking a helmet close to the camera ([as described in this link](http://www.cracked.com/article_20096_6-iconic-movie-scenes-that-happened-by-accident.html)). Only finding out later that Viggo actually broke his toe but they kept this take in.

I would like to know if there are other unscripted scenes which were added in the final take?

Comment: That scene wasn't unscripted though.

Comment: If you've got a spare 12+ hours the extended edition had lots of interesting behind-the-scenes and interviews. Problem was PJ and FW were rewriting lines every day so there wasn't much time of improv. Aragon having a sharpening stone was Vigos idea!

Comment: This isn't a case of improvisation while the cameras were running, but the chant/war dance of Saruman's army before the Battle of Helm's Deep was suggested by the extras playing the Uruk-Hai. It was modeled on the traditional "Haka" of the Maori people of New Zealand which is well known throughout New Zealand (and to all who have seen New Zealand's rugby team play).

Comment: The scene you mentioned in Aragon was not improvised, it was in the script, the only improvised thing about that scene was that Viggo broke his toe, and therefore the scream was much more realistic.

Comment: Remember when Legolas climbed up that elephant and killed it?

Comment: Those scenes in Return of the King where Peter Jackson was asking for completely new SFX assets a month (or so) out from the premiere (source: Appendices in the DVD release)

Answer (score 1):

When Lurtz throws the knife at Aragorn, it was actually a sharp knife and he was supposed to throw it at the tree behind him, but Viggo had the reflexes to deflect it [(found that here)](https://www.gosocial.co/15-movie-moments-actually-bloopers/#post-body-65225:%7E:text=he%20flung%20the%20knife%20right%20at,and%20he%20deflected%20the%20knife%20away)